# Using new codeigniter class instance but without database connection

Tags: database, codeigniter

I'm using a comet like polling system for user notification. The client side uses Ajax to send a 30 seconds long query through a method in a controller class in Codeigniter. On the server side the polling method sleeps 5 seconds after every check for new changes. The whole application uses a database but sice the Ajax call creates a new apache process, calling the method in this controller initialize an unwanted new database connection every 5 seconds. I know I could close the connection with `$this->db->close()` inside the polling method but I suspect that opening an closing the database connection every 5 seconds for a lot of users could result in a big CPU usage.

Is there a way to create an extended instance of the base Codeigniter class BUT **without** a database connection, doing it runtime, without changing the config/database.php?

Something like this:

```
class Controller_without_database extends MY_Controller_with_database {

 function __construct() {
   parent::__construct();

   parent::__killdatabase();
 }

 public function poll(){
    while check_for_changes(); //it uses shared memory not database
    sleep(5);
 }
}
```

Comment: remove `database` library in `config` > `autoload.php` and load where you need.

Comment: WOW, thank you! This is the solution i'll use.